# Diff to HEAD with PHP Storm?

Tags: git, netbeans, phpstorm

How can you see a Git diff to HEAD with PHP Storm?

I'm trying to switch over to PHP Storm from NetBeans as I've heard that it's more powerful. But I can't see how to use the Git diff tool, which was really easy to use in NetBeans IDE.

UPDATE - If I right click on an individual file I can go Git / Compare with latest repository version. This will do a diff to head. However if I try and so the same with a parent folder with multiple changed files the option is greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select file on [Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-with-intellij-idea.html) panel and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to see changes in [Difference Viewer](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/handling-differences.html?search=diff).

Also this nice screencasts: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7kJRkUaVHQ) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLwseyjzmdI) will be so useful for you. *First video about IntelliJ but in PhpStorm this features work with the same way*

### Update:

[image]

Comment: The version control windows is greyed out for me which is strange because I have option in the VCS menu and when I make changes to a file the file the changes are highlighted so it seems Git is integrated.If I go to preferences / version control / Git  and then click Test is says Git executed successfully.

Comment: @jdln When you say `version control windows` do you mean **[Local Changes Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/local-changes-tab.html)** ? *Check update on my answer*

Comment: in older versions it used to be easier than this...there was a button at the top that would let you view for whichever file you were editing...not sure what happened to it