# Diff between commits with PHP Storm?

Tags: phpstorm

Can you see a diff between 2 commits in the same branch with PHP Storm?

With Netbeans you can go Git / Diff / Diff to... and then select the commits. Does PHP Storm have the same functionality?

Comment: Man can you provide response on my answer ?

Comment: I dont have the Version Control panel. Im trying to get this set up so that I can check your answer.

Comment: Version Control panel is that the same panel as in **[previous discussion](http://superuser.com/a/947759/268507)**.

Comment: With the local changes panel I can see changes that havn't been committed yet, but I cant see changes between commits.

Comment: **Log** tab provide information with commits(changes) that already been committed. *Please read my answer again I was provide updates*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes PhpStorm provide this opportunity.

In `Version Control` panel on `Log` tab select any number of commits, holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> and choose commit using mouse cursor:

[image]

Then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and you'll have follow window:

[image]

### [Tips:](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/differences-viewer.html#d1179003e158)

- [image]
  Go To Changed File - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- [image]
   / [image]
   Compare Previous/Next File

---

### YouTube playlist of [IntelliJ IDEA advanced tips & tricks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2Nd9fpteKnV7lDBOl1bYc4sdhR3bu90i)