# Webstorm, compare all project changes against another branch

Tags: git, webstorm, workflow

In Webstorm, there is a "Compare with branch" option, but it seems to only work for specific files. **Is there a way to make it show all changes I have made *in the whole project* since a git revision/branch?** I'd like to have an overview of all the changes I have made since branching away from the master branch, before committing my changes upstream.

The closest thing I've found that is similar is the "compare folder" function, but is seems to only work for folders that exist on the file system (I see no option to compare the root folder with its state a few commits ago, which I imagined could be a workaround).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find all this commits in `Log` tag on the left side and select them by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> if you're Mac user) and on right side all changes will be collected. Now on right side on the toolbar press [image] *Show Diff*.

[image]

See also:

- **[Diff between commits with PHP Storm?](https://superuser.com/questions/959165/diff-between-commits-with-php-storm/959183)**
- **[Diff to HEAD with PHP Storm?](https://superuser.com/questions/946803/diff-to-head-with-php-storm/947759)**

Comment: Hm, maybe I wasn't clear on that but I meant a situation where I have branched away from master and committed several times. If I understand correcly, your answer only works if I haven't committed yet.

Comment: @Ludwik Check updates

Comment: This is fantastic, wasn't even aware of that view. Thanks!

Comment: @Ludwik Glad that I help you )